# Azure container instance not connected kafka cluster

Tags: azure, docker, apache-kafka, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

I have a Azure Container Instance, and I want to connect to a kafka that is also in the azure.
If in kafka configure the advertised.listeners with dns I can connect, however with hostname I can not.
In ACI I also can not ping/wget/telnet to other internal resources, just for other ACIs.

vnet kafka = vnetA
subnet kafka = subnetA

vnet ACI = vnetA
subnet ACI = subnetB

I created the ACI with private ip.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue that the Azure Container Instances connect with other Azure resources. Now the Azure Container Instance just supports a private IP and no DNS labels, and the instances can connect with other resources in the same Vnet or in different Vnet with peering.

> Container groups deployed to a virtual network do not currently
>   support public IP addresses or DNS name labels.

So you can just connect the ACI with the private IP the Vnet. And it just is a preview version. For more details, see [Deploy container instances into an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet)